# Drawing custom paths in D3.js without using fake data points

Tags: d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

Trying to implement EKG style "heartbeat" chart from a design and I'm having a hard time getting D3 to draw a path like I need.

The design spec states that the graph needs to return to nuetral/zero point between each and every data point, and that the curved path from the zero point should be close to the data point itself and rise sharply. See the attached images below

**Here is the design....**

[image: Here is the design]

**And here is my attempt to match the curve with dummy data (black circle data points)...**

[image: monotone path with dummy data points]

The graph has a time scale X axis and a linear Y axis that ranges from 0 to 2 (my data points are 0,1, or 2 respectively). The line is using 'monotone' interpolation which is the least terrible looking.

**Question:** 
Is there a better way to get this appearance without dummy data points?

**Question-behind-the-question:** 
What is the best way to get D3 draw a custom paths (e.g. from a function)?

**Sub-question:** 
Why does the monotone interpolation curve the path inward so sharply between the last 2 data points?

Any help is appreciated! The designers and client won't budge on this one, so I have to get it as close possible :(

Comment: It sounds like you would need a custom line generator.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff can you point me towards a resource?

Comment: [This tutorial](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js) should help with that.